# Groovy default types using def keyword

Tags: performance, groovy

I made simple function in groovy which on datetimes variables, i had such line

```
def minutes = date.getAt(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

and out of curiosity i have checked time performance and it was working 3,5 seconds where size of input has like 90k dates. One simply change from `def` to `int` make my code working in 2,7 -2,5k seconds. `getAt()` returns `int` but minutes has type `BigDecimal` (checked in JMC). Are type inference algorithms so bad in groovy, or i didnt read some part of tutorial about `def` keyword?
Is there any table with default types which will groovy returns when using `def` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getAt() returns int but minutes has type BigDecimal

The type of `minutes` is an integer

```
def minutes = date.getAt(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

you can verify this by running the following in the Groovy shell or console

```
groovy:000> new Date().getAt(Calendar.MINUTE).class
===> class java.lang.Integer
```

`getAt` returns an `int` which is autoboxed to an `Integer` by the call to `.class`.

> Is there any table with default types which will groovy returns when using def ?

The type of the variable does not affect the type by the method, but if you're concerned that Groovy's dynamic typing is impacting the performance of your code, use the `@CompileStatic` annotation.